# Using helper classes inside core class subclass

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am planning to use `anchor()` inside my class which is a subclass of Ci's exception class. I've overridden the show_error() method to contain my custom definitions. I am planning to add a link to my home page for every error page, but it seems that I can't get an instance of CI because it will always error out:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found
```

I can't load the url helpers and other stuff.

Does anyone know how to get the instance of CI or a way to use `anchor()` on a custom subclass of core classes?

Comment: Controller class which has the `CI` instance isn't loaded until after the exceptions class, so it won't be available at that point.